# Kineticjs canvas - smooth drag object

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm trying to get my image to drag smoothly. I'm using this library:
http://candrews.net/sandbox/spryMap/

Here is my attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/aUWY2/

I'm using 'dragend' like so:

```
stage.on('dragend', function(e) {
    stage.transitionTo({
        x: stage.getX() + stage.getAbsolutePosition().x,
        y: stage.getY() + stage.getAbsolutePosition().y,
        duration: 1,
        easing: 'ease-in-out'
     });
});
```

It's not working well. When I drag to right more after I drag to left it's not working. How can I improve it? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is "not working well"?

Comment: when i drag to right more after i drag to left it's not working

Comment: I works exactly as it is programmed to, you drag and you add the absolute position to its current location. What are you trying to get it to do? Describe the behavior you want.

Comment: ^ he probably wants it to look like the example he posted...